# checking for missing options and callback in node

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I have an aysnc function that takes an options object and callback

```
function myFunc(options,callback) {
  // do stuff
  callback(null);
}
```

being the defensive-minded guy that I am, I want to check for any potential problems in the parameters

so the first thing I did was to add a test for the options.name (because I need that property)

```
function myFunc(options,callback) {
  if (!options.name) { callback(new Error("name must be specified")) }
  // do stuff
  callback(null);
}
```

but - this led to a train of thoughts .. what if

- options are an empty or null object
- options where not specified, just a callback passed
- what if no parameters were passed at all ?

---

I want to check that my thoughts are right here -

- options is null / empty. callback is defined -> ***callback with error***
- options is undefined. There are no options and no callbacks -> ***throw a new error***
- options is defined, callback is not

  - typeof options is a function -> ***use options as the callback, with an error***
  - typeof options is not a function -> ***throw an error***

---

so, that's a lot of checks ... do people really do all of this ? What is the best practice to ensure parameters are present and correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question has a sense of personal touch, here's mine:

The purpose of a callback is to provide results of an asynchronous operation. As such, it only needs to be called asynchronously. If anything is prohibiting your code from completing its task, and you can identify that synchronously, either return an error value if one is defined or throw.

If the asynchronous operation failed, use the callback to notify.

***Side note*** `options` can be `undefined` AND `callback` can be a valid function at the same time. Don't assume otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

```
var func = function(p){
if (p == null){
    alert('passed null');
}

if (typeof p === 'undefined'){
    alert('not passed at all')
}
```

you can check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/1s1nqdc7/